# Does Qt require additinal SQLite packages/libraries to be installed?

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt5

I have an idea of storing the configuration of a Qt application in a SQLite database, but I am worrying a bit that Qt SQLite driver may require some additional packages/libraries/dependencies on different OS like Ubuntu, CentOS, Windows, Android etc...

If so, I wonder if anyone knows what exactly should I install and how to ensure that Qt 5.5 prebuilt version, for example, supports SQLite?

Comment: Qt can depend on all sorts of things -- look at all the other questions about deploying Qt apps on Linux, there's already many on this very site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLite 3 library is compiled into Qt (if you have enabled it), so you do not need to install anything else.